# Compatibility with IOS versions 9.3.5 and 11.x (Only one installer)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios, installation, ipa

I have a problem with how can I do for only have one ipa installation for 2 IOS versions.
I don’t know if it’s possible that one .ipa called an other .ipa for install depending the version or configurate the Visual Studio 2017 to work in both. 
The iPad 9.3.5 version is 32 bits and 11.x version is 64.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use one ipa file that can both be installed on ios9 and ios11. The answer is **Yes**.

Firstly in the info.plist set the `MinimumOSVersion` to 9.0.

Secondly right click your ios project > Properties > iOS Build > Supported Architectures. Set it to `ARMv7+ARM64`, also make sure the Configuration is **Ad-Hoc** and Platform is **iPhone**:

[image]

Then turn to iOS IPA Options tab, turn on the **Build iTunes Package Archive(IPA)** check box.

At last build your project, you will find the IPA in bin\iPhone\Ad-Hoc folder. This ipa can be installed on the 32 bits devices or 64 bits devices.

Comment: I had already done that, and I put deployment target 9.0 and it supposes that it had to work from version 9.0 onward but doesn’t work. I don´t know if something I still must do.

When i generate the .ipa and I try to install it in the iPad with version 11.3 I get the message "This app needs to be updated by the developer to work on this version of IOS", but it work with de iPad with version 9.3.5.

On the other hand when I generate the .ipa with target 11.x, it works in that version but no in the iPad with 9.3.5 IOS version.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, i had checked the box enable device-specific builds.